# Execute new process in a destructor

Tags: c#, process, destructor

I have a class which is in charge for error handling. I would like to execute a process, if the destructor is called. But sadly the process would not start. The new processes call an exe with some arguments, which should send an email.
Why does this not work?

```
~ErrorH()
{
    if ((int)e > 0)
        SendErrorMail();
}

private void SendErrorMail()
{
    if (File.Exists("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MailSend\\MailSend.exe"))
    {
        ProcessStartInfo mailsend = new ProcessStartInfo();
        mailsend.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MailSend\\MailSend.exe";
        mailsend.Arguments = "…";
        Process.Start(mailsend);
    }
}
```

If I execute the `SendErrorMail` function for example in the constructor, everything works fine. If I look at the debugger it seems like I reach the `Process.Start(mailsend);` command.
What went wrong? How could I fix this?

**Edit**

Ok now I have used the `IDisposable` method. It works fine, but does is use it correctly?

```
class ErrorH : IDisposable
{
private bool disposed = false;
...
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool desposing)
{
    if(!this.disposed)
        if ((int)e > 0)
            SendErrorMail();
    disposed = true;
}
```

In Program I use:

```
using (Parameter p = new Parameter(args[0]))
{
...
}
```

The class `ErrorH` inheritance from `Parameter`.

Greetz

Comment: Did you try to display a `mbox` in the destructor?? It may never been called yet by GC

Comment: Destructors are meant to be called when the object is garbage collected that you cannot ensure when it happens during your program lifecycle?

Comment: No, but I have tested it actually. The MessageBox appears.

Comment: @Taz Is class `Paramater` implementing `IDisposable`?

Comment: `Paramater` is a subclass von `ErrorH`

Comment: @Taz Ok, your `using` is fine, unless you don't `override` the `Dispose(bool d)` version in `Paramater`. If you want to `override` it in a subclass, make sure you call the base class version by `base.Dispose(disposing)`. Also, remove `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` because you don't need to care about GC.

Comment: @Taz is your final goal, executing the process if something goes wrong in your program? If so you should use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using destructors, which cannot be guaranteed to be called at current time, use interface `System.IDisposable`.

Usually, it is a bad practice to use destructors in C# like C++, for example. Since we cannot determine the specific time the objects will be destroyed by Garbage Collector (GC), C# provides `IDisposable` which has a single method `Dispose`, that you can call it either explicitly when you finish using the object, or implicitly by `using` block.

Comment: Thanks, it works greate, but does I use it correctly? Please see me **Edit**. Greetz